# Trying equal height columns with Jquery on fluid layout - text overflow. :(

Tags: jquery, css

I'm aware of a lot of css nice solutions etc... short being told, I wish this to work, regarding if I have padding, margin, no extra markup, shadows, background colors... so... I'm just looking for a jquery version of it.

Found some on SO. Trying to apply. Seems to work almost. When you narrow the window, text overlaps. If you disable the js, it doesn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/ApUYv/4/

Two questions:

**1) How can we avoid the text from overlapping ?**

**2) Should we use document.ready or window.load ?**

Please note that: `overflow: auto;` may not be an option, because no scroll bar is desirable by the designer. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, whether this is, what you were looking for. But I changed your javascript code to re-adjust the the columns height on window resize: http://jsfiddle.net/ApUYv/6/

```
function resetHeight() {
   var maxHeight = 0;
   $(".equal-height").height("auto").each(function(){ 
       maxHeight = $(this).height() > maxHeight ? $(this).height() : maxHeight; 
   }).height(maxHeight);
}
resetHeight();
// reset height on resize of the window:
$(window).resize(function() { 
    resetHeight();
});
```

To resize the columns when resizing the window, you want to use a callback on `$(window).resize()`, therefor I've encapsulated your code into a function `resetHeight`.

Then, you'll want to recalculate the maxHeight on every call of this function and to do that correctly, you need to reset the height of each div to `auto` temporarily, so that any previous settings won't mess up your `.each()` loop. Also, you need to reset the varaible `maxheight` to `0` each time, because the previous value is still in it.

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I should add that, in order for the height to be properly calculared, at least on my case, I had to use `$(window).load(function(){` for loading it. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't see it overlapping unless i resize it to a very small size. You should consider adding `display:block;` with a [media query](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) for very small screens (like mobile), so that the columns will turn into rows.

Check this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/ALUYr/) of your code with this media query in action:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:400px /*change it to your needs*/) {
    #one, #two, #three, #four {
        float:none; display:block; width:100%; margin:1% 0; height:auto !important;
    }
}​
```

Also, to prevent text from overlapping when the window is resized, wrap your jQuery function into:

```
$(document).on('load resize',function(){
    /* do the resizing stuff */
});
```

2) `$(window).load` will wait until every element of your page (internal and **external**) is loaded, so generally `$(document).ready` is preferable, but it depends on your specific case.

Comment: 2) is solved. The first however, isn't. If you disable the js portion, and you narrow down the window, you will notice that the background will ALWAYS follow the text. :) So the browser, somehow knows how to do this. :s

Comment: Oh sorry, now i got what you mean by "text is overlapping". Just a minute.

Comment: I've updated my fiddle couple minutes ago. My bad. Wrong fiddle. Not you can actually see the equal heights. Also, I'm aware of media queries, but our designer wants to STILL have the columns as columns on a narrow layout. :(

Comment: I loose my resize when using `$(document).on('load resize',function(){ `.

Comment: I see. You should move it into a function, as @Daniel Bakan did in his answer ;) +1 for his reply